# Requesting Proof Verification of a Strict Inequality

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

Prove that if $x_1 \gt  2$ and $x_{n+1} = 1 + \sqrt{x_n-1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ Then $2 \lt x_{n+1} \lt x_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I am pretty sure my work is right but would like verification.

First need to show that both $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ are greater than $2$ for $n=1$ If they are both greater than 2 for $n = 1$ Then they are both greater than two $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then secondly we need to show that $x_{n+1} \lt x_n$.

For $n=1, x_n = x_1 \gt 2$. For $x_{n+1}$ since $x_n \gt 2$ it follows that $\sqrt{x_n - 1} \gt 1$. So it follows that $x_{n+1} = 1 + \sqrt{x_n - 1} \gt 2$. This shows that $x_n, x_{n+1} \gt 2 \space \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Now to prove that $x_{n+1} \lt x_n$

$1 + \sqrt{x_n - 1} \lt x_n$

$\sqrt{x_n - 1} \lt x_n - 1$

Let $x = x_n - 1$

$\sqrt{x} \lt x$

This holds true for $x \gt 1$ which is true when $x_1 \gt 2$ which is our hypothesis.

so we have $2 \lt x_{n+1} \lt x_n$

$\mathbb{QED}$

Comment: "This holds true for $n > 1$ ... " I think you meant "This holds true for $\boxed{x > 1}$ ..."

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.

But choosing $y_n=x_n-1$ would have made it much easier. Then,

**Given**
$$y_1>1 ~~~~\text{ & } ~~~~y_{n+1}=\sqrt{y_n}$$

**To show**
$$1<y_{n+1}<y_n$$

Now, it is easy to see, because $y_n=y_1^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}}$

Hope it helps:)